# Query xml in SQL Server - escaping square brackets

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, escaping

I am trying to query XML in SQL Server but I am getting errors due to my data contains the `[` and `]`.

My XML format (third party so I cannot change this format and get rid of the square brackets):

```
<MyRootElement>
    <MyChildElement name="[Name1]"><MyChildElement>
    <MyChildElement name="[Name2]"><MyChildElement>
    <MyChildElement name="[Name3]"><MyChildElement>
</MyRootElement>
```

I want to get all records where the xml contains a `MyChildElement` with a certain name.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyXmlColumn.exist(N'/MyRootElement/MyRootElement[@name=[Name2]]') = 1
```

SQL Error message:

> XQuery invalid source character: [

If I escape the square brackets of `[Name]`(=`&#91;Name1&#93;`), then it complains about the `&`

So how can I make this query work?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal string should goes in double quotes, no escaping needed for this case :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyXmlColumn.exist(N'/MyRootElement/MyChildElement[@name="[Name2]"]') = 1
```